# Dispatcher: abort dispatcher operation

Tags: wpf, multithreading, datagrid, observablecollection, dispatcher

I want adding items to DataGrid in thread.

I have view model for my user control:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public class ContactGridViewModel
{
    public ContactGridViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Contact> Items { get; private set; }

    public Dispatcher Dispatcher
    {
        get { return Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher); }
    }
    private DispatcherOperation LastOperation { get; set; }

    public void Update(IEnumerable<Contact> contacts)
    {
        if (LastOperation != null) LastOperation.Abort();

        Items.Clear();
        foreach (var item in contacts)
            LastOperation = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                    DispatcherPriority.Background,
                    new ParameterizedThreadStart(o => Items.Add(o))),
                    item);
    }
}
```

There is the markup example:

```
<!--DataContext="{Binding ContactGridViewModel}-->

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone" Binding="{Binding Path=Phone}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

After Update method is executed second time, and if first collection is not completely added, DataGrid will contains part of first collection and full second collection.

```
// contactList1 and contactList2 are IEnumerable<Contact> objects
Model.Update(contactList1);
Model.Update(contactList2);
```

I try to abort DispatcherOperation, but it's not stop adding contacts into Items property.

Could you tell me the correct method of adding objects to DataGrid ItemsSource?

Comment: What does Abort() return? And what part of first collection is remained, first or last?

Comment: @LPL it returns true. Last part of first collection is remained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should collect all DispatcherOpretations in list and then abort them all.

```
public class ContactGridViewModel
{
    public ContactGridViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
        LastOperations = new List<DispatcherOperation>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Contact> Items { get; private set; }
    private ICollection<DispatcherOperation> LastOperations { get; set; }

    public Dispatcher Dispatcher
    {
        get { return Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher); }
    }

    private void StopUpdating()
    {
        foreach (var operation in LastOperations)
        {
            operation.Abort();
        }
        LastOperations.Clear();
    }

    public void Update(IEnumerable<Contact> contacts)
    {
        StopUpdating();

        Items.Clear();
        foreach (var item in contacts)
            LastOperations.Add(Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                    DispatcherPriority.Background,
                    new ParameterizedThreadStart(o => Items.Add(item))),
                    item));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Update(contactList1)` method you start a `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` for every item in contactList1, but if you enter `Update(contactList2)` you abort only once the LastOperation, which is not the complete foreach but an single `Items.Add()`.

Try something like this (not tested):

```
public void Update(IEnumerable<Contact> contacts)
{
    if (LastOperation != null) LastOperation.Abort();

    Items.Clear();
    LastOperation = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        DispatcherPriority.Background,
        new ParameterizedThreadStart(o => { foreach (var item in o) Items.Add(item); }),
        contacts);
}
```

Comment: Have to wait for until all items will be added